# Instruction being skipped is there something I'm not seeing?

Tags: c, ascii, shift, skip

I have this function to convert a character sequence of 7 bits to the actual character it represents (ASCII). So for example, taken the string "1001110" the function should return 'N.'

```
char bits_to_char(char* bits)
{
    byte ret = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < CHAR_SZ; i++){
        if(bits[i] == '1'){
            ret++;
        }
        (ret << 1) && 0xFF;
    }
    return (char) ret;
```

}

The left shift on ret isn't happening. When I step through it with my debugger it just skips it completely. I tried adding a `continue` after the increment on `ret` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Because you're not assigning the result to anything...

Comment: You should be doing the bitshifting before you do the `++` and the conversion to uppercase should be done in the end. See my answer

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
(ret << 1) && 0xFF;
```

at best does the operation and throws away the result.

A reasonable compiler will spot this and optimise it away

Comment: Why? `ret` starts at 0. If I add one to it, `ret` becomes `1`. Now I shift and mask so `ret` is `10`. If I add one to it, it becomes `11`, but if I don't it stays at `10` and then when I do the shift it either becomes `100` or `101`. What does doing the shift before do?

Comment: @Hugo. You need to assign the calculation to a variable i.e. `ret = (ret << 1) & 0xFF;` - Not the one `&` not two and the assigment

Comment: Oh right. I got so used to doing this in assembly that I forgot in C you need to assign it to something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bit-shifting should be done before incrementing the value of `ret`. And converting to upper-case is only necessary when the string has be converted to a value:

```
unsigned char bits_to_char(const char* bits)
{
    unsigned ret = 0;
    size_t size = strlen(bits);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){

        ret <<= 1;
        if( bits[i] == '1'){
            ++ret;
        }
    }
    return (unsigned char) (ret & 0xFF);
}
```